# After submitting the form, dynamically added controls have null values even after input

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

`
savedQueryForm: FormGroup[] = [];

```
createSavedQueryForm() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    queryTitle: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

selectQuery() {
  this.savedQuey = this.tabsInfo[this.selectedTabIndex].savedQueryData.find((query: any) => query.query_id === this.savedQueryForm[this.selectedTabIndex - 1].controls["queryTitle"].value);

  this.queryFields = this.savedQuey.query_fields.map((obj: any) => obj.field_name);
  this.selectedQuery = this.savedQuey.query;
  this.selectedQuery = this.formatQueryString(this.selectedQuery);
  this.queryFields.forEach((field, index) => {
    this.savedQueryHtmlString = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.replacePlaceholders(this.selectedQuery, field));
    this.savedQueryForm[this.selectedTabIndex - 1].addControl(field, new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]));
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  });
}

replacePlaceholders(content: string, field: string): string {
  this.selectedQuery = content.replace("%" + field + "%", '<input formControlName="' + field + '" class="no-focus bg-transparent border-0 border-bottom border-theme text-theme" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="' + field + '" />');

  return this.selectedQuery;
}

submitSavedQuery() {
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.savedQueryForm[this.selectedTabIndex - 1].updateValueAndValidity();
  console.log("###saved query form: ", this.savedQueryForm);
}
```

`

The form controls are added to an HTML string that is added to HTML with [innerHTML]. After entering the values and submitting, the controls added dynamically are listed but have null values.

Tried using
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.savedQueryForm[this.selectedTabIndex - 1].updateValueAndValidity();

but it's not working.

Comment: assigning it the actual Howl object